# Using python to split sql commands in a large sql file

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm trying to create an SQL file that will contain a handful of SQL commands inside of it(commands generally aren't 1 line). I'm going to be using python to parse the file and execute the commands in the order that they appear.

Originally, I was using python.split(';') to split up the file where the commands end and this was working fine. The problem is that now I added functions into my SQL file so they use semicolons throughout the command.

My solution was to add a unique character that will represent the end of a command (I chose '=='). So my SQL file is essentially...

Command #1

==

Command #2

==

Command #3

==

etc.

Since I'm reading the SQL file and splitting it prior to execution, is this solution valid? Or is there a more correct way to go about this issue. It seems to be working as is, but I haven't fully analyzed if all of the commands were properly executed in my database.

Comment: You don't need to divide it up it's a valid SQL file. If you are using a mysql library, you can use `executemany()`. If you are using `mysql` command in a subprocess, you can feed the entire script to stdin.

Comment: @jordanm. If you are talking about the Python  DB API method ```executemany()``` it executes a single command many times, say for doing an ```INSERT``` against a list of values. This will not work for above.

Comment: Why do you want to split the commands?

Comment: All of my commands are different. The sql file is mostly to run the setup for my database schema. It has a create table, creates a few functions, assigns those functions to triggers, etc.

Comment: So my current method with splitting and using '==' works well. But in your opinions, is this a bad way of dealing with the commands?

Comment: You could split ona subset supported DDL commands, assuming each command starts on a new line in column 1.  Use a simple state machine to track lines until next such command.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to trim the SQL file in very specific lines. Because these were very large files, I wanted to be on track when each files are started to be created. So I didn't define my files at once. Here you have my python code :

```
sourcefile = open('mydb-backup.sql', 'r')

newfile1 = open('newfile1.sql', 'w')
for i in range (0, 991665):
    newquery = sourcefile.readline()
    newfile1.write(newquery)
    print(newquery)
newfile1.close()
print("-*-*-*-*-*-*- newfile1.sql created successfully!")




newfile2 = open('newfile2.sql', 'w')
for i in range (991666, 1026740):
    newquery = sourcefile.readline()
    newfile2.write(newquery)
    print(newquery)
newfile2.close()
print("-*-*-*-*-*-*- newfile2.sql created successfully!")



newfile3 = open('newfile3.sql', 'w')

for i in range (1026741, 2184732):
    newquery = sourcefile.readline()
    newfile3.write(newquery)
    print(newquery)
newfile3.close()
print("-*-*-*-*-*-*- newfile3.sql created successfully!")


newfile4 = open('newfile4.sql', 'w')
for i in range(2184733, 2500360):
    newquery = sourcefile.readline()
    newfile4.write(newquery)
    print(newquery)
newfile4.close()
print("-*-*-*-*-*-*- newfile4.sql created successfully!")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).